# How to open port 5814 on AWS EC2 machine. I need to open it for autopass licence server. UFT licence will be installed on autpass server

Tags: amazon-ec2, hp-uft, opentext, microfocus

How to open port 5814 on AWS EC2 machine. I need to open it for autopass licence server. I will install UFT licence on Autopass in server.

https://docs.microfocus.com/doc/AutoPass_License_Server/2023.06/BeforeYouInstall

1. I created virtual machine on AWS EC2
2. installed autopass on EC2
3. Can not ping https://ipaddress:5814/autopass

Why i am unable to ping port 5814?

Answer (score -1):

Please follow below steps -

1. Allow Port From Security Group in Ec2 setting ( Search Google for that )
2. Open Port on windows firewall - Change inbound rule -> Select Port and enter port number and click next till finish

Port 5814 Port is opened now -
Try to ping now - autopass login window will appear

https://ipaddress:5814/autopass

ipadreess - should be public ipv4 address of EC2 machine

Thanks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).